# Spaghetti plot with confidence interval per sequence per visit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some longitudinal data (concentration vs time) for different treatment sequences ans visit. I'm also trying to add the 95% confidence interval for each series.

So far I'm only able to plot one curve with confidence interval for each timepoint, and this for times (one per visit using facet grid), like in the picture .[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8IPi.png)

My dataframe is formatted like this :

- LBTPTNUM (Timepoint corresponding to a concentration)
- mean : which is the concentration to plot versus time
- lower/upper : which are the boundaries of the 95% CI
- USUBJID : Id of each subject
- VISITNUM : number of the visit

I've tried the following code :

```
ggplot(data = CI_spag(), 
       aes(x = LBTPTNUM, 
           y = mean,
           colour = as.factor(TRTSEQP))) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(TRTSEQP))) + 
  facet_grid(~ VISITNUM , labeller = label_both)  + 
  geom_segment(data = CI_spag(), 
               aes(x = LBTPTNUM ,y = lower, 
                   xend = LBTPTNUM, yend = upper, 
                   group = LBTPTNUM, color = "green", 
                   linetype = "dashed" ))
```

But it doesn't returns me what I expect which is something like : 
[what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBpyD.png)

I used geom_segment to represent CI because I haven't found an other solution.

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: It would probably help to define `linetype = "dashed"`, `color = "green"` outside the `aes()` call in `geom_segment`, i.e. `geom_segment(data = CI_spag(), aes(x = LBTPTNUM, y = lower, xend = LBTPTNUM, yend = upper, group = LBTPTNUM), color = "green", linetype = "dashed")

Comment: @teunbrand thanks, it looks better, but I still have only one line per facet where I'm supposed to have 4 (4 curves with CI per facet)

Comment: Yeah that is kind of hard to figure out if we don't have any data that can reproduce your problem.